# Roles checker bot - Discord.js - ReferenceError: member is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, bots

I'm trying to set up a bot for my Discord server. Basically, whenever anyone type "test" to a specific channel (help-channel) the bot will display their roles. If they have a role, say, Baker, the bot will say "You're all set, enjoys them sweet cakes!". If they don't, the bot will say "You do not have the Baker role."

Here's my code:

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
 if (message.content === 'test') {
  if (member.roles.cache.some((role) => role.name === '<Baker>'))
   message.reply("You're all set , enjoys them sweet cakes !");
  else message.reply('You do not have the Baker role.');
 }
});
```

I can't get it to work; the error log said:

```
ReferenceError: member is not defined.
```

Also, I have multiple roles on the server (Baker, Tester, Chief, etc.). So, do I have to write the code for each of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting this error because `member` is in fact, not defined. Instead, you'll want to use [`message.member`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=member)

---

As for your second question, probably yes. Something that comes to mind would be creating an array of every role name and then creating a [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop.

```js
const roles = ['<Baker>', '<Dancer>', '<Programmer>', '<Actor>'];

// iterate a loop through all elements in the array
for (role of roles) {
 if (message.member.roles.cache.some((r) => r.name === role))
  console.log(`${message.author.username} has the ${role} role.`);
}
```

---

You could also mess around with the [`.filter()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=filter) method.

```js
const roles = ['<Baker>', '<Dancer>', '<Programmer>', '<Actor>'];

console.log(
 `Out of the roles in the array, ${
  message.author.username
 } has these roles: ${roles
  .filter((role) => message.member.roles.cache.some((r) => r.name === role))
  .join('\n')}`
);
```

Comment: It works !!!! 

Thanks you very much 


Lemme mess around with the .filter() method aswell , Bless you sir

Answer (score 0):

`member` is not defined that's right. If you want member to be the person who initiated the command you would need to use `message.member`, if you want to get a specified member you could use `message.guild.members.cache.get(<user id here>)`.

And you can shorten your code, by checking for roles using roles' ids, then it would look like `if(message.member.roles.cache.has(<role id>)`. It would also prevent from checking for roles that have same names

Comment: I tried  **if (message.member.roles.has(574540364015337473))** and got the _TypeError: message.member.roles.has is not a function_ 

But worries not i got it working now , thanks you very much

Comment: You'd have to use `message.member.roles.cache.has()`

Comment: Also, you'd have to input `'574540364015337473'` as an argument, not `574540364015337473`. `ID` is mapped as a string.

Comment: Undertstood , lemme try again , thanks you kind sir !